# Snaps to pixel in RenderTargetBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

I write this code to draw a text in a RenderTargetBitmap:

```
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawText(new FormattedText("yes", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Times New Roman"),
                30, Brushes.Red), new Point(10, 10));
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(200, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        image1.Source = renderTargetBitmap;//image1 is an Image control
```

the result is:

[image]

How can I remove this blurry effect? this effect comes from RenderTargetBitmap not from Image control.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`DrawingImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `RenderTargetBitmap`

```
var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
using (var drawingContext = drawingGroup.Open())
{
    drawingContext.DrawText(
        new FormattedText("yes", 
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), 
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight, 
            new Typeface("Times New Roman"), 
            30, 
            Brushes.Red),
        new Point(10, 10));
}
image1.Source = new DrawingImage(drawingGroup);
```

You'll need to create `DrawingGroup` and open `DrawingContext` from there

Comment: yes this is true. But I want use renderTargetBitmap.CopyPixel method.

Comment: then try changing dpi from 96 to say 600: `new RenderTargetBitmap(400, 400, 600, 600, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);`